# Database sharding when the shard key value updates frequently

Tags: database, sharding

I have different availability requirements (e.g. 90%, 95%, 99% guaranteed uptime) for certain subsets of data. For example, the subsets of data are split (sharded?) based on the possible shard key values A, B, C.

**What happens if the key shard value is updated?** Will the corresponding record be migrated to another shard? And does this have a negative impact on the performance?

Initially I thought of just using replication instead of sharding but I don't see how I can differentiate the availability requirements for the different subsets of data. Meaning I need to guarantee 99% for everything.

Comment: This is a platform specific question, but often the sharding key is not allowed to be updated

Comment: Even though it is not really an answer to this question, a relevant variation of this question with a good answer was provided on the Software Engineering StackExchange https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/440063/418230